# Is it possible to create custom simulation functions in KepServerEx?

Tags: kepserverex

We were using in-built simulator function ("USER()") in the "KepServerEx (v6.9)" program to generate values for the tags.

We now want to generate a values in a certain pattern using our own custom logic to meet the purpose. We found that we cannot use any of the in-built simulator functions that could generate the values in the pattern we need.

Is it possible to create a custom simulator function and write the programming logic we need to generate the values, in the KepServerEx?

Answer (score 0):

We do this by creating a second programme to write custom values to the (advanced) simulator tags.

I'd be curious to know, too, if it is possible to link a custom valued function directly into the simulator tags.